# xml version 1.0 encoding utf-8 in php?

Tags: php, xml, validation

xml version 1.0 encoding utf-8  in php, I have tried :

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
```

but this doesnt validate on w3c, when using it in xhtml, the php shows an error.

Whats the easiest way to fix this? With it validating

Thanks

error on w3c:

Line 5, Column 46: character "'" not allowed in prolog

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
```

Line 5, Column 45: XML Parsing Error: Start tag expected, '<' not found

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
```

php error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/public_html//request.php on line 7

```
<?php 
session_start();
include ('../connection.php');
include ('../functions.php');
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
?>
```

Comment: "this doesnt validate on w3c" - and the error message was ...?

Comment: We'll need to see (a) the source and (b) (probably) the output to tell you what's wrong. Saying it "shows an error" doesn't help. What kind of error? Do you get an error message? Does it make your computer explode?

Comment: You do not need to include an XML Declaration for version 1.0 and UTF-8. Those are the defaults, implied if they are missing. The XML Declaration is completely worthless unless you are using XML 1.1 (which almost no-one ever needs to) or a non-UTF-8 encoding (which you should avoid if at all possible). All it serves to do is trip up IE into Quirks Mode in XHTML-as-HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is `short_open_tag = On` in your php.ini

Comment: is it possible to turn these off without accessing the php.ini?

Comment: i believe short_open_tag is non-changeable via ini_set() you would have to access the php.ini directly

Answer (score 3):

I'm inclined to agree w/ @just that this is likely to do with `short_open_tag = On`. Here are a few ways to fix this.

You could break the tag into pieces (short, sweet, and easy, but it has to be done for every instance):

```
echo '<'.'?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?'.'>';
```

You could modify the `php.ini` directly (permanent and holistic, the best solution in my opinion but it requires modifo get IIS ication of `php.ini` and restart of Apache).

Or, you could use [htaccess to define the ini setting for you.](http://davidwalsh.name/php-values-htaccess) This gets around of the issues most of the issues w/ 1 & 2, but it requires Apache (I have no idea how to get IIS to make this work)

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the `<?php` tag at the start of your script?

```
<?php
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
?>
```

Comment: yup it does work by echo'ing just that it doesnt pass and it *needs* to :p

Comment: Is there *definitely no mention* of <?php in the validated source code any more?

Comment: What does the first line of your script look like? If the first line is an XML declaration AND `short_open_tags` are on then you'll get a parse error.

Comment: my guess would be that one of the included files is missing a closing `?>` tag for an opening `<?php`. The error is somewhere in code not shown, as the code example in the question is fine.

Comment: There are no problems in the scripts....its w3c validator finding the error when I echo the xml version/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error messages, sorry if this comes off condescending, but is your code wrapped in PHP opening and closing tags?

That is, does your file look like this?

```
<?php
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
?>
```

Or just this?

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
```

Comment: Yes its wrapped, most of it is xhtml I just start/end php tags where I need to include php.